# SQL: select number of weeks betwene different years

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to group and show the number of registered users per week, from a database.

My code is almost perfect, but it doesn't work correct for year 2016, here is the database:

```
(1, '2013-10-14 16:22:10'),
(2, '2013-12-28 16:22:10'), 
(3, '2014-01-03 16:22:10'), 
(4, '2014-01-08 16:22:10'), 
(5, '2014-06-22 16:22:10'), 
(6, '2014-12-19 16:22:10'), 
(7, '2014-12-27 16:22:10'), 
(8, '2015-01-01 16:22:10'),
(9, '2015-01-07 16:22:10'),
(10, '2015-12-12 16:22:10'),
(11, '2015-12-28 16:22:10'),
(12, '2015-12-29 16:22:10'),
(13, '2016-01-05 16:22:10'),
(14, '2016-01-10 16:22:10'),
(15, '2016-01-15 16:22:10');
```

And this is the query:

```
select  
  str_to_date(concat(yearweek(reg_data), ' monday'), '%X%V %W') as startingweek,
  YEAR(reg_data)*52+WEEK(reg_data, 1) - YEAR('2013-10-14')*52 - WEEK('2013-10-14', 1) + 1 as week_number,
  count(a.reg_data) as nr 
from users as a 
group by yearweek(reg_data, 1)
order by yearweek(reg_data, 1);
```

This is the result, the last 2 rows from 2016 are incorrect, I put in parentheses the correct value that I am expecting:

```
        startingweek        week_number    nr
October, 14 2013 00:00:00      1           1
December, 23 2013 00:00:00    11           1
December, 30 2013 00:00:00    12           1
January, 06 2014 00:00:00     13           1
June, 23 2014 00:00:00        36           1
December, 15 2014 00:00:00    62           1
December, 22 2014 00:00:00    63           1
December, 29 2014 00:00:00    64           1
January, 05 2015 00:00:00     65           1
December, 07 2015 00:00:00    113          1
December, 28 2015 00:00:00    116          2 
January, 04 2016 00:00:00     116 (117)    2
January, 11 2016 00:00:00     117 (118)    1
```

I know the problem is regarding to the number of weeks I use in my query -> 52, because some years have 53 weeks, but I don't know how to make that dynamically change depending on the year.

Also I made a sqlfiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1e5df5/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change the calculation to the number of days between the date and a start date and divide by 7:

```
select  str_to_date(concat(yearweek(reg_data), ' monday'), '%X%V %W') as startingweek, 

   floor(datediff(min(reg_data),'2013-10-14')/7)+1 as week_number,

   count(a.reg_data) as nr
            from users as a 
            group by yearweek(reg_data, 1)
            order by yearweek(reg_data, 1);
```

See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1e5df5/10)

Comment: I tried your query, Can you tell me why it shows week 2, 2 times? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4c046/1

Comment: @Lachesis: I didn't check all possible details, but you use two different `yearweek` calculations, should be the same instead. When you change to `MAX(regdata)` instead of MIN it seems to work. Otherwise change the starting day to a know Monday, e.g. '2013-10-07'

Answer (score 0):

Many databases implement the `datediff()` function. So `DATEDIFF(week, date1, date2)` is what you need. Different databases might use slightly different syntax...